# How can I get the files from nested folders and decorate to showing correctly

Tags: php, file, directory

As shown in title.
How can I get the files from nested folders and decorate to showing correctly.
I succeeded in bringing files from nested folders, but appears incorrectly and Unordered.

This is my attempt:

```
function getfiles($Folder) {
    $dir = opendir($Folder);
    while ($files = readdir($dir)) {
        if ($files == '.' || $files == '..')
            continue;

        if (is_dir($Folder.'/'.$files)) {
            getfiles($Folder.'/'.$files);
        }

        echo $files."<br/>";
    }
}
```

This function work fine, but the result do not appear well and Unordered.

I want to be like this:

```
.folder
   .file
   .file
   .folder2
      .file
      .folder3
         .file
```

Comment: What do you mean by incorrectly and unordered? Do you want to preserve tree structure of just the whole list?

Comment: both = unordered. yes, tree structure

Answer (score 1):

You do not state what your desired output is.

You could for example show the depth in form of indentation:

```
function getfiles($Folder) {
    static $depth;

    $depth++;

    $dir = opendir($Folder);
    while ($files = readdir($dir)) {
        if ($files == '.' || $files == '..')
            continue;

        if (is_dir($Folder.'/'.$files)) {
            getfiles($Folder.'/'.$files);
        }

        echo str_repeat('- ', $depth).$files."<br/>";
    }

    $depth--;
}
```

Or you could use HTML to make a nested structure:

```
function getfiles($Folder) {
    echo '<ul>';
    $dir = opendir($Folder);
    while ($files = readdir($dir)) {
        if ($files == '.' || $files == '..')
            continue;

        if (is_dir($Folder.'/'.$files)) {
            getfiles($Folder.'/'.$files);
        }

        echo '<li>'.$files."</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

If you want a sorted output, use `scandir()`:

```
function getfiles($Folder) {
    $dir = scandir($Folder, 0); // 0 for ascending order, in PHP from 5.4 use SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING
    foreach ($dir as $files) {
        if ($files == '.' || $files == '..')
            continue;

        if (is_dir($Folder.'/'.$files)) {
            getfiles($Folder.'/'.$files);
        }

        echo $files."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just use `<ul>`/`</li>` =)

Comment: good, but Unordered. I want to displays every folder ,its files are below, or tree structure

Comment: Actually it does list every folder with its files below it. Do you mean it's not **sorted**? Use scandir() for that.

Comment: Yes,not sorted. can you tell me plese a small example for Directory Iterator.

Comment: Thanks, I want to using normal way to sorted the folder with its files, but scandir() don't like it .

Comment: Sorry, *DirectoryIterator* cannot do it, but *scandir()* can. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but What I want is Like this 

`folder
 file
 file
 folder2
   file
   folder3`

Comment: Sorry, see my topic in the top, to see what I want.

Comment: And how is the result different from what you want?

Comment: By using scandir(), not appear as I want .

Comment: I'm afraid then we can't help you.